# Elegant way to say "apparently there is no hope, but no, there is still some hope"

Tags: phrase-request

I would like to rephrase the following paragraph (note: for the sake of this question, it is not relevant what CE means; it is only relevant that CE is a good thing):

> "Example 2.1 shows that CE does not exist even in a very simple case. **This example could make us think that there is no hope at all to enjoy the benefits of CE.** However, a recent paper by XYZ (2017) shows that there is still some hope, since this simple case is very rare in practice.".

One problem with this paragraph is the repetitive use of "hope"; another problem is that it is too long and cumbersome. Is there a more elegant way to convey the message that "we could think there is no hope, but yet, there is"?

Comment: How the rarity of the case gives us hope is far from clear. When you say "does not exist **even** in a simple case" it means it doesn't exist where we might most expect to find it, in a simple case. That simple cases are rare doesn't increase the likelihood of CE's existence.    Consider the illogicality here: *Species X is thought to be extinct, and does not exist even in unspoiled habitats. However, since unspoiled habitats are rare, we still have some hope of finding a breeding population.*  By **rare** do you mean "hard to discover"? Many might well exist but they are hard to find?

Comment: @TRomano Imagine a forest with two kinds of tree ...  then everyone dies. Good thing most forests are not that simple.

Comment: @not store bought dirt:  Your example doesn't make clear to me how there is hope for "CE" to *exist* because two-tree-species forests are rare, especially when the likeliest place to find CE is in a forest with only two kinds of trees.

Comment: @TRomano Yeah, that "even" is a problem. But if example 2.1 only proves CE needs some extra help to exist, possibly requiring a complex, unexpected or not yet discovered interaction, then simple being rare is a step in the right direction. Or if the simple case isn't as important as expected the "even" might not be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

A common phrase is:

> [**all is not lost**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/all-is-not-lost)
>   used for saying that a situation is not good but there is still a chance of success

So perhaps:

> However, a recent paper by XYZ (2017) shows that **all is not lost**, since this simple case is very rare in practice."

Comment: This is simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

> "Example 2.1 shows that CE does not exist even in a very simple case. While this may seem hopeless, a recent paper by XYZ (2017) shows reality, since this simple case is very rare in practice.".

For starters, something like that? The word "even" really doesn't make sense, though.